# nodeJS blocking all requests until it calls back

Tags: node.js, callback, blocking, nonblocking, event-loop

I've developed a nodeJS API (using express) which allow users to login and get a list of files that they have stored in a remote server. And as you understand, the code must be non-blocking so the webserver can still responds to logging in requests, even if there are some users fetching theirs files lists.

Every time a user make a request to get his files list, the listOfFiles function is called.

This is the code:

```
exports.listOfFiles = function(req,res){
    db.Account.find({where: {id:1}}).then(function(newAcc){
        console.log("encontrou a account");
        getFiles('/', newAcc.accessToken, '0', newAcc, function(error){
            if (error) {
                log.error('Error getting files');
            }else{
                console.log("callback!")
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**getFiles function**: this function is responsible for fetching the file list from the remote server, and store them in a postgres database

```
function getFiles(path, accessToken, parentID, newAcc, callback){   

    var client = new ExternalAPI.Client({
        key: config.get("default:clientId"),
        secret: config.get("default:clientSecret")
    });

    client._oauth._token = accessToken;

    var options = {
        removed : false,
        deleted : false,
        readDir: true
    }
    //this is the instruction that fetch an array of items 
    //(metadata only) from a remote server
    client.stat(path, options, function(error, entries) {
        if (error) {
            if (error.status == 429) {
                console.log(accessToken + 'timeout')
                setTimeout(    
                   getFiles(path, accessToken, parentID, callback),
                    60000);
            }else{
                log.error(error);
                callback(error,null);
            }
        }
        else {
            //When the array os items arrives:
            console.log("RECEIVED FILES")
            var inserted = 0;
            var items = entries._json.contents;
            for(var file in items){

                var skyItemID = uuid.v1();
                var name = items[file].path.split('/').pop();
                var itemType;

                if (items[file].is_dir) {
                    itemType = 'folder';
                }else{
                    itemType = 'file';
                }

                newAcc.createItem({
                    name : name,
                    lastModified: items[file].modified,
                    skyItemID: skyItemID,
                    parentID: parentID,
                    itemSize: items[file].bytes,
                    itemType : itemType,
                    readOnly: items[file].read_only,
                    mimeType: items[file].mime_type
                }).then(function(item){

                    console.log(item.name)
                    if (++inserted == items.length) {
                        console.log(inserted)
                        console.log(items.length)
                        console.log("callsback")
                        callback();
                    }

                }).catch(function(error){
                    log.error('[DROPBOX] - Filename with special characters');
                    callback(new Error);
                    return;

                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem here is, the moment that webserver prints `console.log("RECEIVED FILES")` in our console, it stops responding to all other requests, such as log in or fetch files requests from other users.

And it starts responding again when it prints `console.log("callback!")`. So, i'm assuming that somehow nodeJS is blocking itself until `getFiles` function is finished and called back.

I think that this is not a normal behaviour. Shouldn't nodeJS be responding to responds to other requests even if there are some operations running in background? Shouldn't `getFiles` function being run in background and not affecting/blocking all other requests? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `createItem()` doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [For loop in callback. Blocking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002047/for-loop-in-callback-blocking)

Comment: mscdex: `createItem()` is responsible to create the Item in the database. It is a function of sequelize (NodeJS ORM) http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same kind of problem for long time server http request blocks the service for response other client requests. This is my topic. [What is the correct behavior for Node.js while Node.js is requesting a long time http request for other servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984806/what-is-the-correct-behavior-for-node-js-while-node-js-is-requesting-a-long-time)  Currently, I got no answer for that. If you got the answer, please reply me. Thanks.