# What is the correct behavior for Node.js while Node.js is requesting a long time http request for other servers

Tags: javascript, node.js

what is the correct behavior for Node.js while Node.js is requesting a long time http request.
The situation is that, my node.js server acts just like a web proxy between client side and db layer(which is exposed by web service). The client will send many requests to Node.js at the same time, the node.js will use request.js pass the requests to the web service. Some of the web services need seconds to get response. Because the handler of response is using callback way in request.js, it should be pushed into the event loop, and the node.js should move to hand over the new request and won't wait for the response. But in my application, the node.js won't process the new request until get the previous response. I am not sure which one is the correct behavior.
For the request.js, I have added a agent in option to avoid blocked by default socket.
`var requestObj = {
            url : targetUrl,
            json : true,
            pool: new http.Agent()
        }`

Please help me on this. If the node.js won't process request until get response, I can't see the reason to use node.js, so I think the issue is caused by my incorrect code. Below are the class to send http request.

```html
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');

function apiService(){}

apiService.prototype.get = function (context, payload, callback, url){
 return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "GET");
}
apiService.prototype.post = function(context, payload, callback, url){
 return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "POST");
}
apiService.prototype.del = function(context, payload, callback, url){
 return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "DELETE");
}
apiService.prototype.requestAPI = function(context, payload, callback, url, method){

 var config = context.config;
 var targetUrl = config.APIHost
     + (config.port == null ? "": (":" + config.port)) 
     + "/" 
     + config.baseDir
     + "/"
     + url;
 
 var requestObj = {
   url : targetUrl,
   json : true,
   pool: new http.Agent()
  }
 
 if (config.proxy != null){
  requestObj.proxy = config.proxy;
 }
 
 switch (method){
  case "POST":
   requestObj.body = payload;
   request.post(requestObj, function (err, resp, body){
    if (err){
     callback(err);
     return;
    }
    callback(null, body);
   });
   break;
  case "GET":
   var queryString = "";
   for (att in payload){
    if (queryString != "")
     queryString += "&";
    queryString += att.toString() + "=" + payload[att];
   }
   if (queryString!="")
    requestObj.url += "?" + queryString;
  
   request.get(requestObj, function (err, resp, body){
    if (err){
     callback(err);
     return;
    }
    callback(null, body);
   });
   break;
  case "DELETE":
   requestObj.body = payload;
   request.del(requestObj, function (err, resp, body){
    if (err){
     callback(err);
     return;
    }
    callback(null, body);
   });
   break;
 }
}
```

**Updated:**
Current process

```
client       request1  ->       Node
client       request2  ->       Node
                                Node    server request1    ->backend
                                Node     <- server response1 backend
client       <- response1       Node
                                Node    server request2    ->backend
                                Node     <-  server response2 backend
client       <- response2       Node
```

What I think it should be

```
  client       request1  ->       Node
client       request2  ->       Node
                                Node    server request1 ->     backend
                                Node    server request2 ->     backend
                                Node    <- server response2    backend
client       <-response2        Node
                                Node    <- server response1    backend 
client       <-response1        Node
```

Comment: From what information are you deducing that Node isn't handling the second request until the first one is done?  What is your backend?  If your backend is not built to handle multiple requests simultaneously, then your backend won't even log that it got a second request until it has finished handling the first request.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new agent instance (a new pool) for every invocation of requestAPI method invocation . A default agentInstance with no maxsockets set will have 5 as its default value.

You could either increase the size of the global agent as in
`http.globalAgent.maxSockets` = Infinity or a high value depending on your reqs and remove the custom pool you have created

or

define the custom pool at the global level and set the maxsockets

```
var myAPIPool = new http.Agent({"maxSockets" : Infinity}); // Infinity or a high value depending on your res.
```

Then use this variable inside your method

```
var requestObj = {
            url : targetUrl,
            json : true,
            pool: myAPIPool
        }
```

**UPDATED**

On playing around with request.js i came to following realization .
If you are calling http methods on request module, the callbacks need to be provided using the on method.
eg. )

```
  request.get(requestObj).on('response', function (response){
                callback(null, body);
            });
```

Similarly you would need to provide error callbacks  chaining this pattern. ie.) .`on("error',cb)` etc

This will give you the expected behavior.

**UPDATED:**

I tested the following code, minor tweaks of your version without any proxies. This clearly logs the calls and when all the calls are finished log
s the callbacks

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');

function apiService() {}

apiService.prototype.get = function(context, payload, callback, url) {
    return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "GET");
}
apiService.prototype.post = function(context, payload, callback, url) {
    return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "POST");
}
apiService.prototype.del = function(context, payload, callback, url) {
    return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "DELETE");
}
apiService.prototype.requestAPI = function(context, payload, callback, url, method) {

    var requestObj = {
        url: url,
        json: true,
        pool: new http.Agent()
    }

    switch (method) {
        case "GET":
            request.get(requestObj, function(err, resp, body) {
                if (err) {

                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }
                callback(null, body);
            });
            break;
    }
}

var apicaller = new apiService();
var url = "http://google.com";
var called = 0;
var cb = function() {
    console.log("called once" + (called++));
}
console.log("calling");
apicaller.requestAPI(null, null, cb, url, "GET");
console.log("calling");
apicaller.requestAPI(null, null, cb, url, "GET");
console.log("calling");
apicaller.requestAPI(null, null, cb, url, "GET");
console.log("calling");
apicaller.requestAPI(null, null, cb, url, "GET");
console.log("calling");
apicaller.requestAPI(null, null, cb, url, "GET");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My current issue is not the size of pool. My current issue is all the node.js won't forward new request until get the previous response. If it is the problem of pool size, The node.js will send 5 requests at least, but currently, only one. Thank you. Would you tell me what is the behavior of your application?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to use the on method. It is still not working. Do you have a sample codes which don't have this kind of issue. I can have a try to make sure it is not a issue of my testing method. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, but it a bit different from what I met. What I met is the client send request to Node, the Node hand over to back end web service. The Node won't response to new client request until it get the response of last request. According to my debug, the code can go over after the apiService.post, it just wait and response to new request after got the response.